# Load local resources in Windows Hosted Web Apps (Project Westminster)

Tags: javascript, css, win-universal-app, hosted-app

I'm currently packaging a website as a "Hosted Web App" for the Windows Store.

Is it possible to check if JavaScript, CSS and image files are already on the users devices inside the app package? This way a lot of traffic could be saved for files that don't change much after all.

Of course there would need to be a fallback to the hosted files in case the site is being called in a normal browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that we're currently investigating and will be enabling more of in the future. Today you are able to access resources from the app package using the `ms-appx-web:///` app protocol to load the resource. You can build this into your website code. We do have a security violation issue when your site is using https (as it definitely should) that we're working on resolving.

Comment: once you've made progress on that feature, could you please let us now and update this answer here? I'm also interested in that feature (see OP).